# does Android Signature Scheme v3 change Android Id Value?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-identifiers

At work I use the androidId as an unique identifier (i know this is not safe) ,the thing is that they are planning to activate the v2 and v3 signature scheme because of security , i'd like to know if this could make the android id change and if so how often ? as we know above android  8  the android  id depends on the keystore and v3  signature scheme rotates the  signing key , i worry about that because one device could generate many identifiers

I have activated the v3 , but the android id did not change , i dont know how often it rotates